# How to block an app from accessing my speaker?

Tags: audio, permissions, speaker

How do I prevent an app from playing audio on an Android?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105764/discussion-on-question-by-user541686-how-to-block-an-app-from-accessing-my-speak).