# How to "Suppress Beep Sound At Recognition Start" on Gboard voice input?

Tags: permissions, volume-control, voice-recognition, gboard, loudspeaker

When using [Gboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin) voice to text input, an atrocious bell sounds to prompt the user to start talking.

<strike>It wakes up the ...</strike>

Sure, I could turn down its volume with the four Android volume sliders. Indeed, on different phones it is on a different sliders. But that doesn't matter, because that is not the solution I am looking for. Why? Because it affects other apps. Throwing the baby out with the bathwater.

Yes, in a Utopian world one could have [A](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/92530/set-different-volume-for-multiple-apps-running-at-the-same-time) and [B](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/222202/how-to-block-an-app-from-accessing-my-speaker), and even my [groundbreaking landmark Android Speaker Permissions proposal](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/277029750). But today I am merely wanting to *deball* this one bell, on my run of the mill Samsung A13 5G Android 13 phone.

The logcat is:

> 04-02 19:24:44.433 I/VoiceInputManager(3099): VoiceInputManager.startVoiceInput():194 startVoiceInput () : VoiceSessionParams{audioInputStream=null, primaryLanguageTag=en-US, secondaryLanguageTags=null, triggerApplicationId=null, triggerFieldName=null, blockOffensiveWords=true, autoStarted=false, fallbackAvailable=false, **suppressBeepSoundAtRecognitionStart=false**, connectOnly=false} : VoiceTranscriptionState : UI = NOT open : Microphone = NOT listening : Recognizer = NOT running

If only I could somehow go in and toggle that **`suppressBeepSoundAtRecognitionStart`** to `true`!

https://support.google.com/android/thread/201115689/google-voice-typing-ding-sound-is-way-too-loud